# Changing value of a temporary table based on condition

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am using amazon redshift and I need to change values for a column called 'codes' in a temporary table like below.

```
id   code
---  ----
1    99990
2    A0002
3    0000F
```

I need to check if the first and last character is numeric , if they both are then change the column value based on its range (e.g set code = 'category1' when 90000 < code < 99999).

If the last character is an alphabet, then set the code based on the range of the first 4 characters (e.g set code = "category2" when 0 < code[:4] < 1000 )

What I have right now is :

```
UPDATE tmp_table
SET code = 'category1'
WHERE substring(code,1,1) ~ '[0-9]' 
AND 90000 <= CONVERT(INT,code) <= 99999 ;
```

However I am getting error for code like 'A0002' , the error message is : Invalid operation, Invalid digit, Value 'A'. 
I suspect the reason is when it fails the first condition , and inside the second condition, the convert function can not take in non-numeric value thus raising the error. But I am not sure how to fix this and get what I want.
Any suggestions ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of evaluation of expressions is indeterminate.  They can be evaluated in any order.

To fix this, use `case`:

```
UPDATE tmp_table
    SET code = 'category1'
WHERE (CASE WHEN code ~ '[0-9]+'
            THEN CONVERT(INT, code) BETWEEN 90000 AND 99999
       END);
```

Or, forget the conversion and just use string logic:

```
WHERE CODE ~ '^9[0-9]{4}$'
```